# Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 2

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to compile a Qt project downloaded from Git hub. I got the following error during the compilation.

**/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 2
****08:33:27: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project FiniteElements (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'******

My .pro file is as below,

```
QT       += core gui opengl widgets
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x000000`
TARGET = FiniteElements
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lqwt

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/qwt/"



SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    FiniteElements.cpp \
    graph_plot.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    FiniteElements.h \
    graph_plot.h
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a space between main.cpp and \ in your .pro file, or this is a typo ?

Comment: with or without space- it makes no difference

Comment: Which qt version ?

Comment: I think I've seen this before somewhere, could be related to this file having been written on windows using \r\n rather than \n for line breaks

Comment: @deW1 right ! That why I suspect the spaces in .pro

Comment: There are some obsolete member functions used in the project, like toAscii in QByteArray class. Does it cause problem?

Comment: @deW1, I removed all the spaces and tried. Still it doesn't make any difference

Comment: @user294664 i don't think so, the error message doesn't refer to any of that !

Comment: may be Try DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0 .... I'm not sure about 0x0000 that you have ...

Comment: i would rename the pro file, create a new file name it as the old one and type down the file as you see it here. you can also use `sed` to replace \r\n with \n but you can google that

Comment: We're talking about https://github.com/MKrishtop/FiniteElements right? Did you use Git to clone the project, or how did you download it? It builds fine for me after fixing up the few necessary Qt 4 to Qt 5 changes, such as replacing all `QtGui` occurrences with `QtWidgets`, replacing `toAscii()` with `toLatin1()`, and linking to the Qt 5 version of Qwt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions tested on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with `qt5-default 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7` and `libqwt-qt5-dev 6.1.2-5` installed:

Clone the repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/MKrishtop/FiniteElements.git
Cloning into 'FiniteElements'...
remote: Counting objects: 17, done.
remote: Total 17 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 17
Unpacking objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Port from Qt 4 to Qt 5:

```
$ cd FiniteElements/
$ find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/QtGui/QtWidgets/g' {} \;
$ find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/toAscii/toLocal8Bit/g' {} \;
$ sed -i 's/-lqwt/-lqwt-qt5/g' FiniteElements.pro
```

For the reference, here's the full diff:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/FiniteElements.pro b/FiniteElements.pro
index a2edb50..610f9f7 100644
--- a/FiniteElements.pro
+++ b/FiniteElements.pro
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ QT       += core gui opengl
 TARGET = FiniteElements
 TEMPLATE = app

-LIBS += -lqwt
+LIBS += -lqwt-qt5

 INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/qwt/"

diff --git a/graph_plot.h b/graph_plot.h
index 551941b..00cf205 100644
--- a/graph_plot.h
+++ b/graph_plot.h
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 #ifndef GRAPH_PLOT_H
 #define GRAPH_PLOT_H

-#include <QtGui/QtGui>
+#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QString>
 #include <qwt_plot.h>
diff --git a/main.cpp b/main.cpp
index 6bf7836..338bba0 100644
--- a/main.cpp
+++ b/main.cpp
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#include <QtGui/QApplication>
+#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
 #include <qwt_plot.h>
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "FiniteElements.h"
diff --git a/mainwindow.cpp b/mainwindow.cpp
index 1f0145f..2ecec7d 100644
--- a/mainwindow.cpp
+++ b/mainwindow.cpp
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#include <QtGui>
+#include <QtWidgets>

 #include "mainwindow.h"

@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@ void MainWindow::browse()
     QString filepath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Select input datafile"),QDir::currentPath());

     if (!filepath.isEmpty()) {
-        std::string str = std::string(filepath.toAscii().data());
+        std::string str = std::string(filepath.toLocal8Bit().data());
         const char * stuff = str.c_str();
         A->SetFN(stuff);
         A->evaluate();
diff --git a/mainwindow.h b/mainwindow.h
index fc8f0fb..4bcf0e1 100644
--- a/mainwindow.h
+++ b/mainwindow.h
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@

 #include <QDialog>
 #include <QDir>
-#include <QtGui/QtGui>
+#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QString>
 #include "FiniteElements.h"
```

Build:

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ qmake
$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qwt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qwt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qwt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o FiniteElements.o FiniteElements.cpp
FiniteElements.cpp: In member function 'int FiniteElements::local_node()':
FiniteElements.cpp:185:6: warning: unused variable 'kf' [-Wunused-variable]
  int kf=0,i=bpn,k=0;
      ^
FiniteElements.cpp:185:11: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
  int kf=0,i=bpn,k=0;
           ^
FiniteElements.cpp:185:17: warning: unused variable 'k' [-Wunused-variable]
  int kf=0,i=bpn,k=0;
                 ^
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qwt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o graph_plot.o graph_plot.cpp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I/home/jpnurmi/Temp/FiniteElements -I/usr/include/qwt -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/c++/5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5 -I/usr/include/c++/5/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qwt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I/home/jpnurmi/Temp/FiniteElements -I/usr/include/qwt -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/c++/5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5 -I/usr/include/c++/5/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include graph_plot.h -o moc_graph_plot.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qwt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o moc_graph_plot.o moc_graph_plot.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o FiniteElements main.o mainwindow.o FiniteElements.o graph_plot.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_graph_plot.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lqwt-qt5 -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
$
```